# Evaluating "exponential like" series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-function

Does anyone know how to evaluate the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{1}{a+k}$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ or if it simplifies things $a\in\mathbb{R_{\geq0}}$. This looks like the exponential series but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Consider the differential of $g(x)=x^a\cdot f(x)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't know what to do...

Comment: I think you'll get $g'(x)=x^{a-1}\cdot e^x$, then you need to integrate it, though I'm not sure how if $a$ is not integer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{1}{a+k} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\int_0^1 t^{a+k-1}dt\\
&= \int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}t^{a+k-1}dt\\
&= \int_0^1t^{a-1}e^{xt}dt
\end{split}$$

Comment: Good catch! Thank you.

Comment: It was actually more than confusing. It was a bad mistake. I hope this time I got this right.

Comment: "Famous last words"... ;-)